# How should I fix this error I am receiving on OnlineGBD?

Tags: c++

on this assignment I and my teacher were developing a bubble sort which would be sorting numbers using this type of code template < typename T > BubbleSortT < std::vector < T >& list >.

This is my code for the three files I'll be using in this in assignment:

```
#include "BubbleSortZ.h"

int main (int argc, char* const argv[])
{
    Test();
    
    return 0;        
}
```

This is the header file:

```
#ifndef BUBBLE_SORT_H
#define BUBBLE_SORT_H
#include <vector>

template <typename dataType>
void BubbleSortZ (std::vector<dataType>& arr);

void Test();


#endif
```

BubbleSortZ.cpp file

```
#include "BubbleSortZ.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template < typename dataType >
void BubbleSort (std::vector <dataType>& arr) {
    std::cout << "Data items in original order:" << std::endl;
    for (std::size_t i= 0; i < arr.size (); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << arr.at (i);          
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    bool changesMade = true;
    for(std::size_t pass = 0; pass < arr.size() - 1 && changesMade; ++pass) {
        changesMade = false;
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < arr.size()- 1 - pass; ++j) {
            if (arr.at (j) > arr.at (j + 1)) {
                
                dataType hold = arr.at (j);
                arr.at (j) = arr.at (j+1);
                arr.at (j+1) = hold;
                changesMade = true;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Data items in pass" << pass + 1 << std::endl;
        for (std::size_t i=0; i<arr.size (); ++i) {
            std::cout << std::setw (4) << arr.at (i);    
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
     }
     std::cout <<"Data items in ascending order:" << std::endl;
}
 
void Test () {
    std::vector < short > shortArr;
    shortArr.push_back (2);
    shortArr.push_back (6);      
    
    BubbleSortZ (shortArr);

    std::vector <double> doubleArr;
    doubleArr.push_back (2.0);
    
    BubbleSortZ/*<double>*/(doubleArr);
    
    std::vector <std::string> stringArr;
    stringArr.push_back("two");
    stringArr.push_back("four");
    
    //BubbleSortZ/*<str::str>*/(stringArr);     
}
```

Though we barely have any issues with these files, we get errors like, BubbleSortZ.cpp:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `void BubbleSortZ(std::vector >&)' /usr/bin/ld: BubbleSortZ.cpp:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to` void BubbleSortZ(std::vector >&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You've implemented `BubbleSort`, but `Test` is calling `BubbleSortZ`.

Comment: The linker is expecting some instance of `void BubbleSortZ(std::vector >&)'`. 
 You've declared template `template <typename dataType>
void BubbleSortZ (std::vector<dataType>& arr);` and you also (inadvertantly) declared some *OTHER* template `template < typename dataType >
void BubbleSort (std::vector <dataType>& arr)`.  In other words: name conflict.

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) Keep the name "BubbleSortZ.h" if you want.  2)  Make sure BubbleSortZ.h, BubbleSortZ.cpp and Test() all use the name "BubbleSortZ" consistently.  3) Consider moving "Test()" OUT of BubbleSortZ.cpp (e.g. into your "main" .cpp.  4) Correctly instantiate `BubbleSortZ<short> bsz1 (shortArr);` and `BubbleSortZ<double> bsz2 (doubleArr);` in "Test()".